# SCM: Storing Credentials

Tags: version-control, credentials

It is generally recommended not to store credentials in a repository. The question is, where should they be stored then, so all developers have access to the same configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stored the config files in a private S3 bucket and manage access via IAM. The configuration updates and revisions are handled by a small script using the AWS gem. That way anybody with sufficient privileges can access them, and we also can issue access credentials for each developer separately.

Answer (score 0):

The question is subjective - different practices may be applied. For me, the approach that worked best is utilisation of some form of "Single Sign-On" where possible and provision of personal logins to every system to developers. This also has an advantage of being able to find out who was responsible for a destructive action (which sometimes happens).

You can also take the approach as described [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/keeping-passwords-in-source-control/): store the credentials in the SCM, but in encrypted form. This will allow to maintain versioning, yet not allow access "for everyone". I'd say, best option is to combine these two approaches (and store only developer-environment "service" credentials - encrypted - in the SCM)